# Why can't I insert element into list inside an array?

Tags: c++, std, stdvector

Why doesn't the code below work? It says "vector subscript out of range". Also, is there a way to get an element from the list using indexes?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    vector<list<int> > adjList;
    adjList[0].push_back(2);
    cout << adjList[0].front();
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect `adjList[0]` to exist? Your vector is empty.

Comment: adjList has zero size, but you are trying to access `adjList[0]`.  That's not going to work.

Answer (score 3):

`adjList[0]` refers to the first `std::list` inside `adjList`. You have an empty vector of lists (`vector<list<int> > adjList;`), meaning that trying to access the first element results in accessing out of bounds.

First you should've added a list to your vector:

```
vector<list<int> > adjList;
adjList.emplace_back(); // adds an empty list
adjList[0].push_back(2);
cout << adjList[0].front();
```